# Transparent button text over the background

Tags: qt, qml

I am trying to make transparent text in qml. 
I have a customized button:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 320
    height:240
    style: ApplicationWindowStyle {
            background: Image { // paste any url here
                source: "https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/01/05/18/57/240_F_105185755_w384KDBvemK5Mn4oXzrWbCz9SRvHuDIh.jpg"
            }
    }
    Button
    {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        style: ButtonStyle
        {
            padding
            {
                left: 16
                right: 16
                top: 8
                bottom: 8
            }

            background:
                Rectangle
                {
                    antialiasing: true
                    color: control.pressed ? "#d1d1d1" : control.hovered ? "#666" : "transparent"
                    border.color: "white"
                    radius: height/2
                    border.width: 1
                }

            label:
                Text
                {
                    text: "buttonText"
                    color: control.pressed ? "white" : control.hovered ? "#00000000" : "white"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

All I want is to have transparent text in button in hovered state. Text should have the color of background. Example: [image: Example]

**upd.** I need this to work without shaders on slow pc.

Comment: Can [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39903639/how-to-apply-opacity-mask-to-a-qml-item) help you?

Comment: @user2436719 I need this example to work on a slow pc with old integrated video card and my program would have lots of buttons. Is there any ability to do it without shaders?

Comment: @Pillar - everything in OpenGL already uses shaders. The shader itself is trivial, barely slower than flat color shading. And NO, you can't do anything in OpenGL without using shaders. And QML uses OpenGL. One way or the other, you will end up using shaders.

Comment: TL;DR: If you're using Qt Quick, you're using shaders already. Shaders make it faster on slow PCs, since they are specialized to do that sort of repetitive processing **very quickly** - at least an order of magnitude faster than the CPU can do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use a custom `QQuickPaintedItem` and use a `QPainterPath` to draw the "text shaped hole".

Basically like this

```
void MyItem::paint(QPainter *painter)
{
    QPainterPath path;
    path.addRect(0, 0, width(), height());
    path.addText(textX, textY, font, yourText);

    painter->setBrush(yourBackgroundColor);
    painter->setPen(Qt::transparent);
    painter->drawPath(path);
}
```

The position, i.e. `textX` and `textY`, would have to be calculated manually I am afraid, though `QFontMetrics::boundingRect()` should help there.